# Soft hyphen support in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Problem: an existing system which prints user entered content (in many different languages) in a PDF report in some cases ends up breaking words incorrectly, for example `"exampl-e"`.

Soft hyphen, is a special invisible symbol which is put in between words and when a word is not fitting and must be broken that symbol will hint the system where it makes sense to do the break.

If the user entered `"exam<theMagicSymbol>ple"` then if the word was to be broken it would be like `"examp-ple"`.

Question: Are there any existing solutions for this in jasperReprots?

Note I'm new to this library, but I couldn't find anything close to soft wraps support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the directly the `textFieldExpression` (in your example use regex `"<[^>]*>"` before printing text) es.

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

**Other solutions are:**

On the jasper `textField` you specify `markup="html"`

Example:

```
<textField>
   <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="2cfd9640-f7ce-4bbe-a024-7b1b53d3b72b"/>
    <textElement markup="html">
      <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field1}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

This will process the text as if it was html, all text formatting code will work as es. `<b>Test</b>` will result it **Test** and all none text formatting code will be removed (es. table, img ecc).

**Final solution**

If you still are not happy, you need more advanced code to format your text, the solution is **your own class** that format the text.

Simple example:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="4" width="100" height="20" uuid="2cfd9640-f7ce-4bbe-a024-7b1b53d3b72b"/>
    <textElement markup="none">
     <paragraph lineSpacing="Single"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[com.my.package.JasperReportTextHandler.format($F{field1})]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Create the java class `JasperReportTextHandler` in package `com.my.package` with static method:

```
class JasperReportTextHandler{
  public static String format(String value){
   //... do your stuff regEx, split...
   return value;
  }
}
```

Just be sure that the `JasperReportTextHandler` is in class path when you execute the report.

Have Fun

Comment: Petter could you please give me few clues where to start, i'm trying to use jasper library without any xml just pure java api... i only need to create a sample page with a table in it (to experiment with hypen thing).

Comment: I'm using 3.5.1 (cause of some issues in future releases that prevent us to upgrade), but i cant find any decent documentation for that version or any tutorial for pure java usage...